# How to get list items using Ajax and rest services

Tags: rest, ajax

Please let me know which "query" to be used...i just copied a sample code from net... please guide me as I am new to ajax and sharepoint

```
function getListItems(url, listname, query, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            complete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me on what condition you want to fetch list item? I mean based on ID or any particular field value ? Because query/filter will changed accordingly.

Comment: based on ID ,i want to retrieve all fields

Answer (score 5):

Here you can use any of the query but before that you must be clear with your own requirement. If you want to get data with specific parameter  (like you want to filter your data) then you can use the following code 

Here i am just updating your code to pass the fieldname and fieldvalue. 
( here i am assuming your list contain only one record, in case of multiple record you need to iterate the loop)

```
function getListItems(url, listname,fieldname, fieldvalue, complete, failure) {

    // Executing our items via an ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$filter= '" + fieldname + "' eq '" + fieldvalue,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        if(data.length > 0){
                var value1 = data[0].fieldName; // this value1 you can assign it into your textbox
        }},
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
    }
```

Let me know whether this helps you or not.

Comment: i need to get values from list and fetch that value to textbox...eg my list contains fields admins,name,DOB,ID etc etc...and these values to be fetched to Textboxes whose Id is as :AdminsId,NameId.....so how to link code and textbox Id

Comment: I edited my answer again, look at the answer

Comment: running on console shows undefined as result and how to assign value1 to textbox?

Comment: how to get lookup field in same code..pls help me out

Comment: In order to get value from lookup column you need to first expand the field and then you can get the value. You can use following rest call to expand. url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$expand='"+ Your lookup column+"'&$select='"+your lookup columnname/fieldWhichYouWantToSelect +"'

Answer (score 1):

You can build your query in several ways and as per your need. But before coping code you have to understand your requirement as well rest api in 2013. Have a look in my article to get started.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: i need to get values from list and fetch that value to textbox...eg my list contains fields admins,name,DOB,ID etc etc...and these values to be fetched to Textboxes whose Id is as :AdminsId,NameId.....so how to link code and textbox Id

Comment: Check in my article. It is already there.

Comment: thans atish fr ur article but really I m new so ...most of things r bouncer...if u cn provide me code for one field..i will manage fr rest

Answer (score 0):

```
query ="?$select=ID,Title"
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query,
```

**ID** and **Title** are the column names of the SharePoint list specified(list name).

**_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl** gives the url of SharePoint.

In success function you will get the ID,Title etc

```
    success: function (data) {
             for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {  
             console.log("Title: "+data.d.results[i].Title);
             console.log("ID: "+data.d.results[i].ID);
}
```

the above codes iterate in each row of SP List